# SQL Server replicating Views - Are underlying tables required to be replicated?

Tags: replication

I have a db with many complicated tables.
I've created views on this db, to simplify this data.

If I replicate these views to a different server, will I need to also replicate the underlying tables?

Answer (score 2):

Yes!

"All types of replication allow you to replicate views. The view (and its accompanying index, if it is an indexed view) can be copied to the Subscriber, but the base table must also be replicated.", [Books Online article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152559(SQL.90).aspx).

Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107532/is-it-possible-to-replicate-a-view-from-a-sql-server-to-another-one) for an answer to a similar question.